# Node.js forever module - get path to a script that is running?

Tags: node.js, unix, forever

When a script is running with the forever module and you "forever list", you get a list with the filenames of all currently running scripts. In this case, "myscript1.js"

```
[0] j2mo /usr/local/bin/node myscript1.js 51004   51005 /Users/me/.forever/j2mo.log 0:14:10:51.420 
[1] Vav3 /usr/local/bin/node myscript1.js 51011   51012 /Users/me/.forever/Vav3.log 0:14:10:21.221
```

Is there a way to get also the path to all running scripts?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Use this to add directory column in the output

```
forever columns add dir
```

Comment: Is there a list of the available columns somewhere?

Comment: can't find the list of the available columns, can anyone help. Thanks

Comment: Here are all the available columns answer: https://github.com/foreverjs/forever/issues/542

Comment: Great! This should be the default! It is super useful for dev/prod deployments!

Answer (score -1):

```
ps aux | grep forever
```

This prints all running scripts and you can match them with the "pid" column in "forever list"

Comment: This command has the same issue as Forever list. If your scripts have the same name in never shows the full path to the actual script.

Comment: Must be the Amazon Linux VM I'm using. Was able to use this: ps auxe | grep forever

Comment: Does not answer the question.